# python suds without internet connection

Tags: python, soap, client, suds

I'm using suds for accessing SOAP server but it's failling. Same with this issue unfortunately the suggested work-around isn't working.
[suds failed without internet access](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/soap/2011-May/000453.html)

The problem with suds is that it tries to download from the internet
XMLSchema.xsd
without success:

```
DEBUG:suds.xsd.sxbasic:Import:0xb7808a6cL, importing ns="
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", location="
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd"
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
.....
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
```

Comment: I can't recall the details, but I've had success making copies of the cache files in `/tmp` and periodically copying them back there. I think I had to manually set the cache folder to a static path. You need an active internet connection to generate the cache files first though.

Comment: my observation is that it is ok to have timeout as there is no internet connection as you are connecting to some resource which can be accessed through internet.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Import.bind() thing wasn't working for me so I went into the suds source code and did some fiddling. 
Go to /suds/transport/http.py.
Add the following to the open method in the HttpTransport class.

`if url == "http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime":
     url = 'file:///SOAP_Schemas/2005.xml'`